# Creating a list of arrays with positive and negative values from given set in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Let say I have the following set `A={1,2,3}`

Now I want to create a list of array such that my output looks like 
(if we are allowed only 1 negative value)
`{-1,2,3}, {1,-2,3}, {1,2,-3}`

(if we are allowed only 2 negative values)
`{-1,-2,3}, {-1,2,-3}, {1,-2,-3}`

... And so on.

So far, I tried for when I have 1 negative value, and it works.
I used two for loops as below

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

for (int j=0; j<neighbours.size(); j++) 
{
    outer.add(createDnf(neighbours, neighbours.get(j)));
}

protected ArrayList<Integer> createDnf(List<Integer> others, int dn) {
    ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j=0; j<others.size(); j++) {
        if(others.get(j) == dn) {
            inner.add(dn);
        } else {
            inner.add(-others.get(j));
        }
    }
    return inner;
}
```

Here `neighbours` contain a list of integers same as set `A`.
How can I make it work for 2 or more negative values?

Thanks!

Comment: watch out, p over q grows pretty fast. Example: if your list has 50 elements  (p) and you allow for 6 negative values (q), your output will have (50*49*48*47*46*45)/(1*2*3*4*5*6)=15,890,700 values.

Comment: Wonder if this is a case of back-tracking algorithm, starting first element, making it -ve and then working on the remaining elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have created the below snippet, its giving repeated value only in case of you require single negative digit, otherwise it is working fine:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
                        ArrayList<Integer> negativeIndexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        negativeIndexList.add(1);
                        negativeIndexList.add(2);
                        negativeIndexList.add(3);
                        negativeIndexList.add(4);
                        negativeIndexList.add(5);
                        System.out.println(returnPositiveNegativeArray(negativeIndexList,2));



    }

    private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> returnPositiveNegativeArray(List<Integer> inputList,int noOfNegativesInEachList)    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> rList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(int index=0;index<inputList.size();index++)    {

            for(int j=index+1;j<inputList.size();j++)    {

                ArrayList<Integer> negativeIndexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                negativeIndexList.add(index);
                for(int k=j;k<inputList.size();k++)   {
                if(negativeIndexList.size()<noOfNegativesInEachList)    {
                                    negativeIndexList.add(k);

                }

            }
                if(negativeIndexList.size()==noOfNegativesInEachList)    {

                    ArrayList<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    innerList.addAll(inputList);
                    for(int negativeIndex:negativeIndexList)    {
                        innerList.set(negativeIndex,-innerList.get(negativeIndex));
                    }
                                    rList.add(innerList);
                    }


            }

        }
        return rList;
    }
}
```

See if it can help you..

Comment: Thanks for your code snippet. However, it works for only when `noOfNegative=2`. For `noOfNegative>2` it does not return the complete list.

Comment: For 3 negaives ot is returning [[-1, -2, -3, 4, 5], [-1, 2, -3, -4, 5], [-1, 2, 3, -4, -5], [1, -2, -3, -4, 5], [1, -2, 3, -4, -5], [1, 2, -3, -4, -5]]

For 4 it is giving [[-1, -2, -3, -4, 5], [-1, 2, -3, -4, -5], [1, -2, -3, -4, -5]]
For 5 :[[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]]

Which set do you think is missing

Comment: For 3 negatives and 5 elements in the set, it should have `5C3` elements which are equal to 10.
So missing combinations are : [-1, -2, 3, -4, 5], [-1,-2,3,4,-5], [-1, 2, -3, 4, -5], [1, -2, -3, 4, -5]

Comment: I really dont think that is the correct way to verify it(though I am very bad at this permutations and combination).  Check the result which I have posted and let me know which set is missing